# How to conditionally display div's child based on whether parent div has focus or not?

Tags: angular

I want to conditionally render content of div. I have multiple blocks like below and want to do same for each one. What's the clean way to achieve this?

```
<div class="sidebarBlock"  tabindex="-1" >

            <!-- display if sidebarBlock don't have foucs-->
            <div>
       <img src="../../../assets/icons/dashboard.png" class="iconstyle" >
       <span class="iconText">Dashborad</span>
    </div>
    <!--display if sidebarBlock has focus-->
    <div>
        <img src="../../../assets/icons/blue_dashboard.png" class="iconstyle" >
        <span class="iconText">Dashborad</span>
     </div>
    <div>
        <img src="../../../assets/icons/dashboard.png" class="iconstyle" >
        <span class="iconText">Dashborad</span>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `.ts` file define some boolean variable like `someFlag`

then in the html use `*ngIf=someFlag`

The result will be - only if this variable is true, the div will be displayed, else will be hidden.

Example:

### example.ts

```
export class Example {
  ...
  someFlag:boolean = true;
  ...
}
```

### example.html

```
<div id="parent"
      (focusin)="this.someFlag=true" (focusout)="this.someFlag=false">

   <div *ngIf=this.someFlag">
      <p>bla bla...</p>
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I want to display contens based on focus.basicaly what I'm looking for is somethinglike *ngIf="parent.hasfocus()"

Comment: @Arjun, ok, what do u mean when you writing `parent` ? whole html written above is the child, and other parent component contains it ? or you just mean to the top level div here above it's the parent ?

Answer (score 0):

if By focus you mean hover then
Basically you want to hide blue_dashboard image on hover

html:

```
<div class="sidebarBlock"  tabindex="-1" >
    <div class="blue">
        <img src="../../../assets/icons/blue_dashboard.png" class="iconstyle" >
        <span class="iconText">Dashborad</span>
     </div>
    <div>
       <img src="../../../assets/icons/dashboard.png" class="iconstyle" >
       <span class="iconText">Dashborad</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.sidebarBlock:not(:hover) .blue {
  display: none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it using formControl in you .ts file.

And in the HTML, you can use *ngIf="parentFormControlName.focus"